# JAVA - Can we ignore SSL verification for local network

Tags: security, ssl, https, certificate, ssl-certificate

Can we ignore SSL verification for local network. My case is-

I have two applications deployed in a system. These two applications cannot communicate through internet, due to some security constraints. the two applications can communicate using their private IPs. But the certificate issued by CA is valid only for the public IP (accessible from internet), so when they tries to do a HTTP connection, it throws a Subject Alternative Name invalid exception.

I cannot use alternate certificate.

Please suggest if we can configure Java / JREs of the applications to ignore SSL validation?
Please suggest any alternate solution, if any.

Comment: Should perhaps be asked on superuser or serverfault.

Comment: could you add the public host name to the HOSTS file so that it resolves locally to the private IP?

Comment: @jglouie I tried doing that. but that doesnt works.

Comment: @user2531191 Do you get a different validation error, or the same host mismatch error?

Comment: Do you really have a SAN-certificate that is valid for the public IP-Address or for the FQDN?

Comment: There are a couple of reasons why this might not work. One of them being Javas own certificate storage that might doesn't support your CA out of the box. So please give us more information about the actual certificate in usage.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you might just be better off using HTTP on the local network.

If you need transport layer security on your LAN, you can probably use a VPN or SSH tunnel instead. And it sounds to me like you don't really need this, as you're OK with ignoring SSL handshake errors, which makes using SSL in the first place kind of moot.

You can set up your servers to listen on two ports, one for external requests over HTTPS, and one for internal requests on HTTP.

You can either set up your firewalls so that HTTP is only available from LAN IPs, or alternatively only listen on localhost and use a VPN or SSH tunnel to the target server and do the requests via the tunnel.